# Can JQPrint be configured or modified to ignore checkboxes?

Tags: jquery, jqprint

I am using JQPrint to print the contents of a  of an html report I generate. Unfortunately I must have checkboxes on the screen for each row, but I would like to be able to print without the checkboxes. Is there any way to do with this JQPrint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can provide a print CSS and write a rule that hide checkboxes. jqPrint respects print CSS.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.yourcsspath/print.css" media="print">
```

Or you can provide extra CSS.

**[From documentation](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/jqPrint)**:

> **importCSS** - Css links in original page will be imported into iframe.
>   First it searchs for media='print', if there isn't, will be imported
>   the normal css files.

Example

```
$('#toPrint').jqprint({
  importCSS: 'http://www.yourcsspath/print.css'
});
```